# MongoDB and user specific documents -- Spring Security backend

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security

I am trying to find out the best way to go about this before implementing.

I have a Java Web Application that is using Spring MVC and will be using Spring Security (with an LDAP server whenever I can figure out how that works).

I have a collection of "Organizations" and I have two requirements.

```
1) Each logged in user should be able to store their own "Organization" and view only theirs.
2) There should be a concept of "public organizations" that a user can set an "Organization" document to so everyone can view them.
```

A user can have many Organization documents, this is simply a modeling tool.

To be honest, I'm not sure how Spring Security will be hooking up to my companys LDAP server yet, I'll be figuring that out sometime this week. So I'm not sure how Users get managed with that.

Will every document need a UserID and maybe a boolean value stating whether the document is public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a UserID on each document is probably going to be necessary so you can keep track of who created it.

As far as sharing with others goes, if you know public is the only thing you'll ever need, a boolean would probably be enough.  If you end up needing anything more, you could nest a permissions document in your top level document containing keys like 'read', 'edit', 'delete', with the values being lists of people able to perform those operations, you could also create a "PUBLIC" user that you can add to those groups as desired.